# Cocos2D in UIKit app?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, uikit

Right now I am properly and completely implemented Cocos2D and FontLabel (Cocos2D needed file), into my project. I need to use Cocos2D in only one of my UIViews. Does anyone have any tutorials or tips they can give me so I can use Cocos2d like I usually would but just in my UIView in my UIKit app?

Answer (score 2):

The second edition of my book [Learn iPhone and iPad Cocos2D Game Development](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/store/book-learn-cocos2d/) has a chapter on Cocos2D with UIKit integration, both for adding UIKit views to Cocos2D as well as adding Cocos2D to an existing UIKit app.

If you're looking for example code try the UIKit template project provided by [Kobold2D](http://www.kobold2d.com), although it doesn't contain the "UIKit app with Cocos2D" example.